# PgAdmin4 "the application server could not be contacted" Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, pgadmin

I updated my OS to Ubuntu 19.04. I had been using pgadmin4 on Ubuntu 18.10 and it worked without problems, but now that I have updated I get this error:

> the application server could not be contacted

I tried uninstalling pgadmin4 and reinstalling but without improvement.

I also reactivated the postgresql repository because when updating to Ubuntu 19.04 I deactivated some repositories.

Comment: is your postgres server running?

Comment: HI @Kenetch did something worked for you? I am still having this issue.

Comment: Hi @AndrewJamesRamirez. the desktop application does not work, but I installed the version of apache2 and that works well for me, currently I use everything with docker, but at the time I use it with apache.

Answer (score 3):

Try following the advice in this article: [How to Install and Configure pgAdmin4 on Ubuntu 18.04 & 16.04](https://tecadmin.net/install-pgadmin4-on-ubuntu/)

Remove the previous installation

```
sudo apt-get remove pgadmin4
```

and reinstall

```
sudo apt-get install wget ca-certificates
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pgadmin4 pgadmin4-apache2
```

for me it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had to do

```
sudo mkdir /var/cache/pgadmin/
```

before starting pgadmin4.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 20.04, If,

```
sudo python3 /usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py
```

gives an error,

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/cache/pgadmin/sessions'
```

Simply create the missing file path as,

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/pgadmin/sessions
```

and rerun,

```
sudo python3 /usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py
```

For output as below -

```
$ sudo python3 /usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py
NOTE: Configuring authentication for SERVER mode.
Enter the email address and password to use for the initial pgAdmin user account:
Email address: what_ever@email_u_like.com
Password: 
Retype password:

pgAdmin 4 - Application Initialisation
======================================

Starting pgAdmin 4. Please navigate to ***http://127.0.0.1:5050*** in your browser.

 * Serving Flask app "pgadmin" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
```

This would present the pgAdmin4 login window in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Just try from terminal :

```
$ pgadmin4
```

It will result just like this :

```
Python path:  "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages" 
Python Home:  ""
Webapp path:  "/usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"
```

If it doesn't work ,copy webapp path and 
You can start it manually:

```
$ sudo python3 /usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py
```

Answer (score 0):

First find the ports running of your 'username' by:

> pkill '**username**' ex: pkill '**postgres**'

now use **pkill** to **safely** kill all the running process

> sudo pkill **postgres**

And at last, restart your postgres server.

> sudo service postgresql start